# What is the Nba Log Category?

Tags: apex, debugging

I was tweaking my log settings today and noticed this oddity:

[image: Nba Log Category]

Notice to the right of `Wave` appears a new Log Category: `Nba`.

The `Tooling API Developer Guide` specification for [`TraceFlag`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_traceflag.htm) does not even include Wave as far as I can tell. What is the nature of this new category?

Comment: Is it some sort of Easter Egg related to the playoffs or something? Or is it real?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I too wondered what this was when the pre-release orgs were updated:

> What is a #Salesforce Nba in #Summer18 and why is it so important that it gets its own Debug Log Category? #askforce - [tweet](https://twitter.com/fishofprey/status/983877422289317888)

The general consensus was it stands for **N**ext **B**est **A**ction. This is related to Einstein predictions/insights.

> An anonymous source found a lightning:nextBestActions component in the auradocs for #Summer18.
> Checks out for Nba as it has strategies like the log messages. [tweet](https://twitter.com/FishOfPrey/status/984169375425900544)

[image]

There is a Summer '18 pilot that appears to be related: [Use Strategies to Recommend Flows to Users and Community Members](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_distribute_nba.htm)

> We provide Einstein **Next Best Action** to selected customers through a pilot program [...]

I've also [documented the current logging levels](http://www.fishofprey.com/2018/05/salesforce-log-categories-and-events-by.html) for it.

> **Nba-Error**
>
> - NBA_STRATEGY_ERROR
> - NBA_NODE_ERROR
>
> **Nba-Fine**
>
> - NBA_STRATEGY_BEGIN
> - NBA_STRATEGY_END
> - NBA_NODE_BEGIN
> - NBA_NODE_END
> - NBA_OFFER_INVALID